# search sql from checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox

i have a checkbox group

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ckflood[]" value="VerySafe"> Very Safe
<input type="checkbox" name="ckflood[]" value="Safe"> Safe
<input type="checkbox" name="ckflood[]" value="Average"> Average
<input type="checkbox" name="ckflood[]" value="Heavy"> Heavy
<input type="checkbox" name="ckflood[]" value="VeryHeavy"> Very Heavy
```

and this is the table

```
*City        Flood*
Paris       Safe-Average
Milan       Heavy
London      VeryHeavy
Rome        Average-Heavy
Athena      VerySafe
```

How to show city(Rome,Milan,Paris) as the result when i checked 'average' and 'heavy' checkbox
Then it gives 'Rome' 100 score, 'Paris' and 'Milan' 50 Score

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where you getting error.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT City from tableName WHERE Flood IN('Average','Heavy')"
```

Comment: How (Average,Heavy) you have got from checkbox. Please show that code also.

Comment: which language u r using on server side?

Comment: User have tag PHP in question.

Comment: that's static sql code, but my case is dynamic sql which the condition from check box

Comment: `"SELECT City FROM tableName WHERE Flood IN (".implode(',', $_POST['ckflood']).")"`

Comment: from above statement it will comes without quotes. E.g: (heavy,average) and its give error.

Comment: sorry  beacuse it is string you have to quotes the value in ''
`"SELECT City from tableName WHERE Flood IN('Average','Heavy')"`

Comment: above i have written same but with dynamic so its more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use implode() to merge ckflood values and then use it in query.

```
$comma_separated = implode("','", $_POST['ckflood']);
$ckflood = "'".$comma_separated."'";

$query = "SELECT City from tableName WHERE Flood IN(".$ckflood.")";
```